# How to pack .gem file with changes

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-1.9.2

I have one doubt,

I am able to unpack the gem 'herubyracer-0.9.9.gem' using this command

```
gem unpack therubyracer-0.9.9.gem
```

I am getting therubyracer-0.9.9 folder
Changelog.md  Gemfile  README.md  Rakefile  bin/  ext/  lib/  spec/  specmem/  specthread/  therubyracer.gemspec

and I have copied the v8.so file to /lib directory

Please let me know, how can i make .gem file with above included (I have copied the v8.so file to /lib directory) change.

Answer (score 2):

you need to obtain a `*.gemspec` file for your original gem

if you don't have a gemspec, you can create your own gem with help of `jeweler` gem

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  I have already have the gemspec file, but after some modification in gem folder and how to pack the gem with changes. thanks for advance

Comment: edit gemspec and add your new files to files array, and then issue a `gem build` command

Comment: Hi,  Please let me know how to build the gem different arch. I have tried this it is not working "gem build therubyracer.gemspec ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" "